# How to set default keychain via cli in mac?

Tags: macos, security, command-line-interface, keychain

I got this error after deleting the default keychain expecting that MacOS will pick the available one as default but it did not.

> security: cert import failed: A default keychain could not be found.
> security: problem decoding

I want to set the default keychain using cli

Answer (score 17):

```
security default-keychain -s "/Users/ted/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
```

Found it in

```
man security
```

Comment: is it per session or it would be a permanent change ?

Comment: permanent. Use fastlane to create temporary keychains